# Are webservices better suited for downloading a file via an url than web pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm currently in the process of redesigning an old ASP.Net project. 
Intere a normal ASP.NET page was used and depending on the url a specific file from the server was downloaded via writing the files contents to response.

Now as no output is needed from that url other than the file itself and the page got the filename via querystring I began to wonder if there would be any point in leaving it as a web page or making a web service out of it.

But even after some reading up I'm not sure if a normal ASP.Net page or a web service would be better suited for this (thus having more advantages and less disadvantages when doing that).

So my question would be, does anything speak in favor of any of the two methods?

Comment: I think here you have implementation details which you haven't shared yet, so I mean we may need to see use cases, otherwise it might be opinionated to answer. Though I think that adding a web service would only make it "better" if you need to integrate this webservice as an API to some other code or (sub)system.

Comment: @kayess the only thing not mentioned is that the webpage got called from c# code (via networkshareaccessor and streams).

Answer (score 0):

When queried only from other machines / applications, a WebService is probably better: authentication might differ, access restrictions could apply, it could run inside a DMZ or behind a firewall instead of public, and it is more lightweight (less resources used).